# ESC's get armed, spins briefly and then stops

Tags: raspberry-pi, brushless-motor, esc

[image]

My team is building an AUV using a Pi4. We are using 1000KV 12-24V brushless motors and 30A Brushless ESCs. We are running the motors currently with python using pigpio. The code I have now can arm the ESC's (I think). using set_servo_pulsewidth() It goes 0, 750, wait to arm, then goes to 1650. It will spin briefly or twitch and then stop. I tested out the pi to esc connection with a basic servo motor and the pi's sending out its signal loud and clear.
Previously we tested the motors with a Arduino and it seemed to do something similar where it come on briefly and then stop completely.
What could the issues be? Is it an issue with the ESCs or the motors?

I'll attach links to the motors and ESC's below.

[www.walmart.com/ip/Suzicca-1000KV-Underwater-Brushless-Motor-Clockwise-4-Blade-Propellers-12-24V-Waterproof-Electric-Drive-Engine-RC-Bait-Boat-Nest-Ship/521754712?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=101043443](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Suzicca-1000KV-Underwater-Brushless-Motor-Clockwise-4-Blade-Propellers-12-24V-Waterproof-Electric-Drive-Engine-RC-Bait-Boat-Nest-Ship/521754712?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=101043443)

https://www.rcelectricparts.com/classic-esc-user-guide.html

Comment: FWIW-- when I've written code for hobby ESCs or hobby PWM boards I've noticed they can be very inaccurate when it comes to the actual values produced. That can lead to the ESCs receiving pulsewidth values slightly outside the expected range which causes them to de-arm. A fix is to instead never send the full range of possible pulsewidth values (just trim off the top and bottom, say, 5%). 

You should also plug this into an oscilloscope to verify that you're actually getting the accurate values for the arm/command sequences.